# Undefined method error for scope on STI subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

### The Setup

I have an STI setup like so:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account

  scope :deposits, -> { where type: Deposit }
end

class Deposit < Transaction
  scope :pending, -> { where state: :pending }
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end
```

If I call:

```
> a = Account.first
> a.transactions.deposits
```

...then I get what I expect, a collection of `Deposit` instances, however if I look at the class of what's returned:

```
> a.transactions.deposits.class
```

...then it's actually not a Deposit collection, it's still a Transaction collection, ie. it's a `Transaction::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`

### The Problem

So, to the problem, if I then want to call one of the `Deposit` scopes on that collection it fails:

```
> a.transactions.deposits.pending
NoMethodError: undefined method `pending' for #<Transaction::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f8ac1252d00>
```

### Things I've Checked

I've tried changing the scope to `Deposit.where...` which had no effect, and also to `Deposit.unscoped.where...` which actually returns the right collection object, **but** it strips all the scope, so I lose the `account_id=123` part of the query so it fails on that side.

I've checked this and the problem exists for both Rails 4.1 and 4.2. Thanks for any pointers on how to make this work.

### I know there's a workaround, but...

I know I could work around the issue by adding a `has_many :deposits` into `Account`, but I'm trying to avoid that (in reality I have many associated tables and many different transaction subclasses, and I'm trying to avoid adding the dozens of extra associations that would require).

### Question

How can I get what's returned by the `deposits` scope to actually be a `Deposit::ActiveRecord_Association...` so that I can chain my scopes from `Deposit` class?

Comment: could you possibly delegate the `pending` scope to the `Transaction` class?

Comment: How could I do that? `Deposit` is a subclass of `Transaction`, the call stack goes **up** the inheritance chain, so once the method call reaches `Transaction.pending` how would I get it back down to `Deposit.pending`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an isolated test for your issue here:https://gist.github.com/aalvarado/4ce836699d0ffb8b3782#file-sti_scope-rb and it has the error you mentioned.

I came across this post from pivotal http://pivotallabs.com/merging-scopes-with-sti-models/ about using were_values in a scope to get all the conditions. I then used them on `unscope` to force the expected class, basically this:

```
  def self.deposits
    conditions = where(nil).where_values.reduce(&:and)
    Deposit.unscoped.where(conditions)
  end
```

This test asserts that it returns a `Deposit::ActiveRecord_Relation` https://gist.github.com/aalvarado/4ce836699d0ffb8b3782#file-sti_scope2-rb

#### Update

You can also write this as a scope if you prefer:

```
  scope :deposits, -> { Deposit.unscoped.where where(nil).where_values.reduce &:and }
```

Answer (score 2):

As a quick workaround you can do `> a.transactions.deposits.merge(Deposit.pending)`, but can't think of a different way of solving it. I'll think and try more options later and come back if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to say that an Account `has_many :deposits`

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :deposits
end
```

Then you should be able to query

```
a.deposits.pending
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to do that. I have a number of classes with associations to transactions, and a number of other subclasses besides deposits. I am trying to avoid this specific workaround.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to avoid this solution as a workaround? In the app I maintain we use this setup pretty regularly.

Comment: I'm not avoiding the workaround, I was already using it. I'm trying to see whether there's a way to do what I want without having to add the dozens of extra `has_many`s and changing the existing calls to use those instead of what they've been using before I added these scopes on the subclasses.

Comment: I see. I haven't come across a solution like you describe. If I do, I'll come back and post it here. =)